# View contextual log option is not being show for event logs sent by fluentd

Tags: elasticsearch, logging, kibana, fluentd

I am sending the application logs from fluentd to elasticsearch, I am not able to see the view contextual logs in elasticsearch UI and I have added the  data format which is sent to elasticsearch from fluentd below

```
{
  "took": 12,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": 1,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "xxxxxx",
        "_id": "xxxxxxxxx",
        "_score": 1,
        "_source": {
          "filename": "access.log",
          "hostname": "app",
          "remote": "172.x.x.x",
          "host": "-",
          "user": "-",
          "method": "GET",
          "path": "/status.js",
          "code": "200",
          "size": "17",
          "referer": "-",
          "agent": "kube-probe/1.21",
          "@timestamp": "2023-04-27T07:05:12.000000000+00:00"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

how to get that view contextual option in elasticsearch UI with above format data? could anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

I tried to change message field to type text and ensured timestamp is passed along with event logs but still view in context option is not shown

Answer (score 0):

`host.name` and `log.file.path`; these two fields are required to get the view in the context option of Kibana UI. So I had to include these two fields in the events that are sent from fluentd to elasticsearch.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).